# Can I check buy app at app store form users clicks facebook ads

Tags: facebook, ads

I want to get count of users who buy app form facebook ads,
Is possible to check it?

Answer (score 0):

Measure App Installs

Yes facebook App ID.
If you measure your mobile app ads for installs, you will be able to:

Improve campaign performance - You will begin to see installs reported as well as the Cost per Mobile App Install (CPI) in your Ads Manager.
Get more effective and more advanced bidding options - You can set a cost per action (CPA) bid to better manage your budget while maximizing installs, or use oCPM to optimize for audiences most likely to install your app.

[See This here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ads-for-apps/measurement)